# Right Joycon buttons aren’t working

Tags: nintendo-switch

My right joycon buttons (specifically a,b,x,y, home, +, R and ZR buttons) haven’t been working for a few months now. I have tried two different joycons, both of them don’t work. I have all the recent system and controller updates. The left joycon works fine. The right one doesn’t work both attached and not attached. What is the problem?

Comment: Since this issue has affected two different joycons, you should check that the buttons are not unassigned. From the Switch Home menu select System Settings, Controllers and Sensors, and then Change Button Mapping, and make sure each button is assigned to something. (This is unlikely to be the issue as you can't remap the Home button, but it's worth a check).

Comment: It sounds like a standard joycon issue to me. If the methods described above by Showsni don't work, I would send them to repair, get a refund, or buy new ones, depending on where you are and how easy it is to do so. Sorry to hear about this.

Answer (score 1):

Nintendo Switch Joycons have been notoriously inconsistent in their quality. Many players, including myself, have experienced Joycon drift. While I haven't heard of buttons failing to work I would believe it.

There are guides online of how to send your Joycons back to Nintendo for repair, or you could [look at their repair page directly](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/ask/ht/789), which is an option if you prefer to use Joycons.

I, however, bought a compatible controller for my Switch and haven't had any issues with that yet. Because I both prefer the feel of the controller, and it seems more durable I would recommend purchasing that instead.